# Are there any benefits to reaching a high Hit Streak?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

In Final Fantasy XV, there is a Hit Streak counter that increases every time you hit an enemy consequently within a certain time frame, generally without interruptions. In most battles, I will reach anywhere between a 5 - 10 Hit Streak before either the battle ends or it breaks due to either healing or being hit. In tougher battles, I can reach nearly a 100 Hit Streak when using Armiger.

[image]
*Picture taken from Google Images*

I have put many hours into Final Fantasy XV and I not seen any differences between a 5 Hit Streak and a 100 Hit Streak. Are there any benefits to reaching a high Hit Streak?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there's an Ascension skill that increases damage the higher your hit counter gets, called Chained Fury.

From [the wiki page](http://finalfantasyxv.wiki.fextralife.com/Chained+Fury):

> Boost damage dealt when unscathed during chain attacks.

Unless you have this Ascension skill, the hit counter doesn't really do much, though.